# Home router network disappears from network list

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

My home network periodically disappears from the network list of my recently install Ubuntu 19.04 PC. Other PCs and phones see that network with no problem.

This is the output from terminal on network adapter:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list  
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)  
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]  
Kernel driver in use: wl  
0: phy0: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
2: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes  
Hard blocked: no
```

I know the router broadcasts on two frequency bands, 2.4GHz and 5GHz. This PC's adapter doesn't see 5GHz, but I should see the WLAN in the 2.4GHz band.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Perhaps you could us get more diagnostic info by seeing what 
`tail -f /var/log/syslog` gives you?

Comment: @Fala Matroskin Your Broadcom BCM43142 and all 802.11n-capable devices are  5GHz capable as well as 2.4GHz capable.  https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2014/12/30/802-11ac-vs-802-11n-wifi-whats-the-difference/#144a1c8c3957

Comment: I will try to get the diagnostic when it disappears. It does that periodically. Also, I don't see the 5G network on this computer even though the router is broadcasting both at the same time. Is this a driver issue?

Comment: I reinstalled the wireless driver. So far the network is on, but it still doesn't see the 5G network.